# Batch rename my classes to change my project prefix?

Tags: xcode, file, automation, rename

I've created a project and built out a several model classes. I've decided that I'd like to recycle them as a separate framework. In doing so, I want to change my class prefix of those files. The issue is, of course, that I now have to batch rename my files and my classes. I could use the refactor tool, but I have tens of classes, so it would be tedious. Is there a good way to automate the process? For reference, I'm using Xcode 5.

Comment: You could maybe do it with AppleScript (or in ObjC via ScriptingBridge), but a quick scan over the Xcode scripting dictionary makes it look like file references are largely immutable.

Comment: @DaveDeLong I worked out how to do it, but it took more effort than I might have expected from Xcode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, I think I have a solution, although it's something I'd like to see built in to Xcode. I've filed a radar.(#15261680)

I had three things to worry about here:

1. The class names themselves. The class prefixes didn't match the framework that I wanted to put them in.
2. The file names. Even if I did a careful global search and replace and changed the class prefixes, the file names would be wrong.
3. The Xcode project references. Xcode keeps a list of your files, and I had to be sure that Xcode would know where to find my files, in the event that I renamed them.

What I did:

1. I did a global search and replace. Instead of clicking "Replace All", I used the "Review" pane, so I was able to exclude about ten or so cases that I wanted to keep with the original prefix.
2. I found a utility to do a batch rename. Now my files and classes all match nicely.
3. Uh oh! Xcode doesn't know where my files are, now. To fix this, I opened the .pbxproj file and did another careful search and replace. (I made sure to quit Xcode first, so my changes wouldn't be overwritten automatically.)

This was a bit of an involved process, and I was hoping that there was a tool or Xcode feature to help me do this, but alas, not yet.

Comment: Great procedure.  I'd very much like to know which utility you used to batch rename your files.

Comment: A very good tool to use is automator. There is a nice tutorial for it: http://www.wikihow.com/Batch-Rename-Files-in-Mac-OS-X-Using-Automator

Comment: There's a FREE utility for Mac OS X called [NameChanger](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/) for batch file renaming.

Comment: Note for anyone reading this since Yosemite, there is a built-in batch renaming function now. Select all the files you want to rename in Finder (it can be after a search) then right click and go "Rename..." > Replace Text